# NullPointerException - getCellTpeEnum() POI

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I working with Apache POI and in particular getCellTypeEnum.
I have a problem with my program, I get the error NullPointerException when I'm reading a file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbLine; i++) { 
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < nbCol; j++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()){
                case STRING:
                fileData2[i][j] = df.formatCellValue(cell);
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                fileData2[i][j] = NumberToTextConverter.toText((cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

When I try a file smaller than my original file it's working well but when I try with the original and bigger file, it returns me the NullPointerException.
Cheers in advance guys !

Exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at t6.jFrame.jButton5ActionPerformed(jFrame.java:506)
at t6.jFrame.access$400(jFrame.java:40)
at t6.jFrame$5.actionPerformed(jFrame.java:239)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: can you post the Exception stack?

Comment: Posted on the main message!

Comment: I would suggest to try to simply debug to begin with. Which row is being read when you get the NPE? You could use "conditional breakpoints" to stop only when   cell is null.

Comment: In fact, I tried with smaller file and it's working well but when I try with the original (biggest) file I got the error. I will try the conditional breakpoint and I keep you uptade Asap

Comment: You should test the cell of possible null values and handle all cell-types in your switch statement and then react on null values.

Comment: It is really weird... I checked on the debugger, I did an System.out.print on all data with 'i' and 'j' and it's corresponding to my array defined before... I also read all the data of my file and at the end it  returning me the error

Comment: I did this,`cell= row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK); `. Still not working, sorry for the delay I was off.